# Solution for TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, typeerror

I'm new to everything that implies JavaScript and I don't understand the error. I documented myself a little bit, and some say that the error might be caused by a ill-written function or something like that.

These are my classes

> bookApi.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Book = require('./Screens/Book');

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Book.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(book => res.json(book))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({noBook: 'No book found!'}));
});

module.exports = router;
```

> Book.js

```
import Book from '../bookApi';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nume: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    autor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    editura: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    poza_coperta: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    gen: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    descriere: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    nota_medie: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    nr_recenzii: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    nr_pagini: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    data_publicarii: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    stoc: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = Book = mongoose.model('book', BookSchema);
```

I also have classes in which I use it like this:

```
const BookCard = (props) => {
    const book = props.book;
```

and

```
import Book from '../bookApi';
```

The last is the only importing method that at least didn't give me an error compiling the code in the cmd prompt, but the 'TypeError' appears and I don't understand the reason.

I tried to adapt this example to my project: https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-stack-tutorial/

The error says this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
D:/Torrents/Other-Files/Team Project/test/test1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
View compiled
```

./node_modules/express/lib/response.js

```
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:83006:30
__webpack_require__
D:/Torrents/Other-Files/Team Project/test/test1/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
```

EDIT: My mistake is that I wrote the backend code inside my react app (frontend), which, as a friend told me, would make the libraries 'fight' with each other, thus leading to the crash of the app. Solution: separate backend from the frontend. Create an independent directory for your react app where you will keep only the frontend, and another directory in the folder you have the react app directory where you only keep the backend. e.g. `app/client` for frontend, `app/server` for backend.

Comment: The code looks  ok. What is the error you are getting? Can you include it in your post?

Comment: @SteveTomlin I did now, is it enough?

Comment: also, forgot to mention, in the textfields or something similar, I use it like this ```{Book.descriere}``` because with 'book' it was saying 'book is not defined.'

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of this error is VScode adding a line in your react code importing express like the line below

```
// remove
import e from 'express';
```

verify at the top of the rwct file you are working on whether such a line exists at the top. Remove that line.